# Alternatives for XAutoClicker (without X11 Installation)

Tags: xorg, alternative

I'm searching for an alternative for xautoclicker. I need an autoclicker that can click really fast, so e.g. Slickbot is no option.
Since everybody seems to use xautoclicker, i tried that. But it needed the installation of X11, and that crashed my whole system (black screen after system start). GTK+ or QT would run xautoclicker too, but I'm afraid of another black screen...
So is there another program I can use?
My sytem is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: X11 is the base graphical system on which GTK+ and Qt are built. So if you want GUI auto-clicking, you *need* an X11 install. Also, if you installed Ubuntu Desktop, X11 is already installed.

Comment: when i try to install xautoclicker, it says that X11 is not installed...

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: like it's said in the installation guide, i ran the ./configure

Comment: I suppose you have a graphical environment installed?

Comment: take a look if http://www.murguu.com/ fits your needs

Comment: @user281916 I know, but unfortunatly it's not free, and I don't want to pay 10$ for an autoclicker ^^

Comment: @BharadwajRaju yes, i think it's Unity

Comment: @An00bis88, where did you read that? You can download it right on the page

Comment: @user281916 it stands in the readme and I got a message to, after using it for 1 month,  get a regestration key

Comment: Then you absolutely *must* have X11. File a bug or something - tell them that their X11 detection is broken.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the following commands helped!

```
sudo apt-get install g++

sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

i use MaxAutoClicker, you can find how to download and install it here https://maxautoclicker.blogspot.com/2021/05/mouse-auto-clicker-for-ubuntu-linux.html

download link from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxautoclicker